# prometheus still getting metric value even target is down

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I used prometheus in k8s cluster to monitor multiple containers , each container expose their metrics , and I got all metrics value from prometheus GUI , but the strange behavior comes when i shutdown container , metrics for this container still available from prometheus for more than 5 minutes even target is down

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the default behavior. In abstract form, the metrics are stored at one location and Prometheus looks at the location when running promql queries. When you stop the application/container, it will not delete delete those metrics as that is extra work for the application.

Comment: Hello , i don't think so , because when  running  prometheus in my local PC , promql query said empty data  just after interval=scrap interval + timeout